# How to use Java Comparator to sort by last character in string?

Tags: java, comparator

Say I have an inventory map :

```
Map<String, Integer> inventory = new TreeMap<>()
```

and I want to sort inventory by the last character in the String, how would I do this with a Comparator? How would I handle errors if it's an empty string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can define a simple comparator:

```
 Comparator<String> comp = Comparator.comparing(s -> s.length() > 0 ? s.substring(s.length()-1) : "");
```

then you can instantiate a treemap with that comparator:

```
 Map<String, Integer> map = new TreeMap<>(comp);
    map.put("xxxa", 11);
    map.put("pppb", 2);
    map.put("lllc", 3);
    map.put("iiid", 3);
```

to get this output:

```
{xxxa=11, pppb=2, lllc=3, iiid=3}
```

Answer (score 4):

A treeMap is sorted based on its keys. Also a treemap doesn't contain duplicate/null keys.

You can write a custom comparator to sort inventory by the last character in the String.

Try this:

```
Map<String, Integer> inventory = new HashMap<>();

inventory.put("inventk", 3);
inventory.put("inventc", 5);
inventory.put("inventa", 8);
inventory.put("inventx", 2);
inventory.put("invento", 1);

inventory.entrySet().stream().sorted(new Comparator<Map.Entry<String, Integer>>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(Entry<String, Integer> e1, Entry<String, Integer> e2) {
        String s1 = e1.getKey();
        String s2 = e2.getKey();
        if (s1.length()>0 && s2.length()>0) {
            s1 = s1.substring(e1.getKey().length() - 1);
            s2 = s2.substring(e2.getKey().length() - 1);
        }

        return s1.compareTo(s2);
    }
}).forEach(e -> System.out.println(e.getKey() + " " + e.getValue()));
```

Output:

```
inventa 8
inventc 5
inventk 3
invento 1
inventx 2
```

Comment: Or `Comparator.comparingInt(str -> str.charAt(str.length() - 1))`.

Comment: @chrylis -on strike of course this is better

Answer (score 1):

Below code helps you to compare the key string by its last character

```
Map<String, Integer> inventory = new TreeMap<String, Integer>(new 
MyNameComp());
inventory.put("aaz", 11);
inventory.put("aab", 2);
inventory.put("zza", 3);
inventory.put("zzax", 3);
inventory.put("zzax", 4);
inventory.put("", 3);
System.out.println(inventory);
```

and create the class named MyNameComp that implements the comparator

```
@Override
public int compare(String s1, String s2) {
if (s1.isEmpty()) {
return -1;
} else if (s2.isEmpty()) {
return 1;
} else if (s1.isEmpty() && s2.isEmpty()) {
return 0;
}
int res = -1;
// return 1 if last char of s1 greater than last char of s2
if (s1.charAt(s1.length() - 1) > s2.charAt(s2.length() - 1)) {
res = 1;
}
// return 0 if s1 and s2 are equal
else if (s1.equals(s2)) {
res = 0;
}
// return -1 if last char of s1 lesser than last char of s2
return res;
}
```

Comment: We can use  Character.compare(char, char) but the problem is if it returns 0 then it will update the value for the key. for example **inventory.put("aaz", 11);
inventory.put("bbz", 2);** will replace aaz with value of 2. It will not create new key with bbz.

Comment: Yeah exactly. If we use the comparator to construct the map by small change it will change the behavior of the map itself. for example instead return 0 if return 1 map will allow duplicate key as well.